# how i make WebView work onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, onclick, android-webview, onclicklistener

i try to make URL or webview work on onOptionsItemSelected is that impossible 
I am actually a beginner in the android

this my code

I really hope to find a solution to this problem
This is the subcode that I would like to run

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.context_menu:
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ContextMenuDialogFragment.TAG) == null) {
                    mMenuDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, ContextMenuDialogFragment.TAG);
                }
                break;
            case R.drawable.icn_1:
                mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://twitter.com");
                break;
            case R.drawable.icn_2:
                mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://youtube.com");
                break;
            case R.drawable.icn_3:
                mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://www.newsweek.com/us");
                break;
            case R.drawable.icn_4:
                mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://yahoo.com");
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

this my full code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMenuItemClickListener, OnMenuItemLongClickListener {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private ContextMenuDialogFragment mMenuDialogFragment;
    private XWalkView mXWalkView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mXWalkView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        initToolbar();
        initMenuFragment();
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue, R.color.purple);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {


                mXWalkView.reload(url);
            }
        });

        loadweb();
    }


    public void loadweb() {

        mXWalkView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mXWalkView.setResourceClient(new ResourceClient(mXWalkView));
        mXWalkView.setUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(mXWalkView) {
            @Override
            public void onPageLoadStarted(XWalkView view, String url) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageLoadStopped(XWalkView view, String url, XWalkUIClient.LoadStatus status) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
        mXWalkView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mXWalkView.setLongClickable(true);

        mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }


    private void initMenuFragment() {
        MenuParams menuParams = new MenuParams();
        menuParams.setActionBarSize((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tool_bar_height));
        menuParams.setMenuObjects(getMenuObjects());
        menuParams.setClosableOutside(false);
        mMenuDialogFragment = ContextMenuDialogFragment.newInstance(menuParams);
        mMenuDialogFragment.setItemClickListener(this);
        mMenuDialogFragment.setItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    private List<MenuObject> getMenuObjects() {

        List<MenuObject> menuObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        MenuObject close = new MenuObject();
        close.setResource(R.drawable.icn_close);
        MenuObject send = new MenuObject("Send message");
        send.setResource(R.drawable.icn_1);
        MenuObject like = new MenuObject("Like profile");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icn_2);
        like.setBitmap(b);
        MenuObject addFr = new MenuObject("Add to friends");
        BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icn_3));
        addFr.setDrawable(bd);
        MenuObject addFav = new MenuObject("Add to favorites");
        addFav.setResource(R.drawable.icn_4);
        MenuObject block = new MenuObject("Block user");
        block.setResource(R.drawable.icn_5);

        menuObjects.add(close);
        menuObjects.add(send);
        menuObjects.add(like);
        menuObjects.add(addFr);
        menuObjects.add(addFav);
        menuObjects.add(block);
        return menuObjects;
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TextView mToolBarTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_toolbar_title);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.btn_back);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        mToolBarTextView.setText("Samantha");
    }

    class ResourceClient extends XWalkResourceClient {

        public ResourceClient(XWalkView xwalkView) {
            super(xwalkView);
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(XWalkView view, int progressInPercent) {

            progressBar.setProgress(progressInPercent);


            if (progressInPercent == 100) {
            }
            super.onProgressChanged(view, progressInPercent);


        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.context_menu:
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ContextMenuDialogFragment.TAG) == null) {
                    mMenuDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, ContextMenuDialogFragment.TAG);
                }
                break;
            case R.drawable.icn_1:
                mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://twitter.com");
                break;
            case R.drawable.icn_2:
                mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://youtube.com");
                break;
            case R.drawable.icn_3:
                mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://www.newsweek.com/us");
                break;
            case R.drawable.icn_4:
                mXWalkView.loadUrl("http://yahoo.com");
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMenuItemClick(View clickedView, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMenuItemLongClick(View clickedView, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mXWalkView.evaluateJavascript("onBackPressed()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(final String value) {
                if (!Boolean.valueOf(value)) {
                    MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```